# How to print only msg

Tags: debugging, ansible, element, msg

How to hide the excess and why is it printed?

Also, why is null not printed for {{ item.1.drive_letter | default('null') }}

Playbook:

```
---
- name: get windows disk size 2
  hosts: TEST
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
  
  - name: register win_disk_facts
    set_fact:
      disks: "{{ansible_facts.disks}}"
  
  - name: print free_space of total_size
    debug:
      msg: 
        - "{{ item.1.drive_letter | default('null') }}: {{ (item.1.volumes[0].size_remaining | int / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) | round(1) }} of {{ (item.1.size | int / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) | round(1) }}GB"
    with_subelements:
      - "{{disks}}"
      - partitions
      - flags:
        skip_missing: true
```

Expected:

```
TASK [print free_space of total_size] ***************************************************************************************************************
    "msg": [
                "null: 0.1 of 0.5GB"
            ]
```

Fact:

```
TASK [print free_space of total_size] ***************************************************************************************************************
ok: [TEST] => (item=[{'bootable': True, 'bus_type': 'ATA', 'clustered': False, 'firmware_version': '0.10.2', 'friendly_name': 'QEMU HARDDISK', 'guid': None, 'location': 'PCI Slot 0 : Adapter 0 : Channel 0 : Device 0', 'manufacturer': None, 'model': 'QEMU HARDDISK', 'number': 0, 'operational_status': 'Online', 'partition_count': 2, 'partition_style': 'MBR', 'path': '\\\\?\\ide#diskqemu_harddisk___________________________0.10.2__#5&158eda0f&0&0.0.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}', 'physical_disk': {'allocated_size': 25769803776, 'bus_type': 'ATA', 'can_pool': False, 'cannot_pool_reason': 'Insufficient Capacity', 'device_id': '0', 'firmware_version': '0.10.2', 'friendly_name': 'QEMU HARDDISK', 'health_status': 'Healthy', 'indication_enabled': None, 'manufacturer': None, 'media_type': 'Unspecified', 'model': 'QEMU HARDDISK', 'object_id': '{1}\\\\TEST\\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\\SPACES_PhysicalDisk.ObjectId="{640e5765-60a5-11ec-8899-806e6f6e6963}:PD:{5d0bb3ee-a263-28e1-46ee-2df09b319ea6}"', 'operational_status': 'OK', 'partial': True, 'physical_location': 'PCI Slot 0 : Adapter 0 : Channel 0 : Device 0', 'serial_number': 'QM00001', 'size': 25769803776, 'spindle_speed': 0, 'supported_usages': {'Count': 5, 'value': ['Auto-Select', 'Manual-Select', 'Hot Spare', 'Retired', 'Journal']}, 'unique_id': '{5d0bb3ee-a263-28e1-46ee-2df09b319ea6}', 'usage_type': 'Auto-Select'}, 'read_only': False, 'sector_size': 512, 'serial_number': 'QM00001', 'size': 25769803776, 'system_disk': True, 'unique_id': 'IDE\\DISKQEMU_HARDDISK___________________________0.10.2__\\5&158EDA0F&0&0.0.0:test', 'win32_disk_drive': {'availability': None, 'bytes_per_sector': 512, 'capabilities': [3, 4, 10], 'capability_descriptions': ['Random Access', 'Supports Writing', 'SMART Notification'], 'caption': 'QEMU HARDDISK ATA Device', 'compression_method': None, 'config_manager_error_code': 0, 'config_manager_user_config': False, 'creation_class_name': 'Win32_DiskDrive', 'default_block_size': None, 'description': 'Disk drive', 'device_id': '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0', 'error_cleared': None, 'error_description': None, 'error_methodology': None, 'firmware_revision': '0.10.2', 'index': 0, 'install_date': None, 'interface_type': 'IDE', 'last_error_code': None, 'manufacturer': '(Standard disk drives)', 'max_block_size': None, 'max_media_size': None, 'media_loaded': True, 'media_type': 'Fixed hard disk media', 'min_block_size': None, 'model': 'QEMU HARDDISK ATA Device', 'name': '\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0', 'needs_cleaning': None, 'number_of_media_supported': None, 'partitions': 2, 'pnp_device_id': 'IDE\\DISKQEMU_HARDDISK___________________________0.10.2__\\5&158EDA0F&0&0.0.0', 'power_management_capabilities': None, 'power_management_supported': None, 'scsi_bus': 0, 'scsi_logical_unit': 0, 'scsi_port': 0, 'scsi_target_id': 0, 'sectors_per_track': 63, 'serial_number': 'QM00001', 'signature': 2060161686, 'size': 25769802240, 'status': 'OK', 'status_info': None, 'system_creation_class_name': 'Win32_ComputerSystem', 'system_name': 'TEST', 'total_cylinders': 3133, 'total_heads': 255, 'total_sectors': 50331645, 'total_tracks': 798915, 'tracks_per_cylinder': 255}}, {'access_paths': ['\\\\?\\Volume{7acb9296-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\\'], 'active': True, 'drive_letter': None, 'guid': None, 'hidden': False, 'mbr_type': 7, 'number': 1, 'offset': 1048576, 'shadow_copy': False, 'size': 575668224, 'transition_state': 1, 'type': 'IFS', 'volumes': [{'allocation_unit_size': 4096, 'drive_type': 'Fixed', 'health_status': 'Healthy', 'label': 'Зарезервировано системой', 'object_id': '{1}\\\\TEST\\root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/Providers_v2\\WSP_Volume.ObjectId="{640e5765-60a5-11ec-8899-806e6f6e6963}:VO:\\\\?\\Volume{7acb9296-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\\"', 'path': '\\\\?\\Volume{7acb9296-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\\', 'size': 575664128, 'size_remaining': 154927104, 'type': 'NTFS'}]}]) => {
    "msg": [
        ": 0.1 of 0.5GB"
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure, as I do not have a windows to test this ... But I think this would go something like this:

```
  - name: print free_space of total_size
    debug:
      msg: |
        {{ (item.1.volumes[0].size_remaining | int / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) | round(1) }} of {{ (item.1.size | int / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) | round(1) }}GB
    loop: "{{ disks | subelements('partitions', skip_missing=True) }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item.1.drive_letter | default('null') }}"
```

The `with_subelements` is deprecated (FYI), might be replaced by a `loop`. And as of using a loop, you can set a `label` for each item that is processed. Which then replaces the full item dump you see in your logs.

See:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-subelements
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#limiting-loop-output-with-label

As an FYI, simplified version I used testing this, on Linux:

```
  - name: print total_size
    debug:
      msg: |
          {{ disk.value.size }}
    loop: "{{ ansible_devices['nvme0n1']['partitions'] | dict2items }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ disk.key }}"
      loop_var: disk
```